# Installed android app - full screen not accessible

Tags: android, android-layout

I've installed an android app which requires actually three input fields to be filled on the initial setup. But in my mobile only two input fields are shown, third I couldn't access as there is no scrolling option.

In other mobiles with larger display all the three input fields are shown.

Can I access the installed location of an Android App in my mobile?

If yes, Can I make changes to configuration of that app so that It scrolls in smaller displays?

Note: I am not an android developer.

Thanks.

Comment: Without modyfing the app's code you it is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably that is problem with the application itself. You can't do anything other than UN-installing the application. The only way is buy a phone with bigger screen or get the application fixed by the app providers. You can add your comment on the application at 
https://play.google.com/store/. Search the application and write your review, probably they may fix the issue.